# Traveling inside the USA with a ead card?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I live in Tx, but plan to visit my father in NM. I have a EAD card with advance parole. Can I get through checkpoints without a problem?

Comment: What sort of checkpoints do you expect to encounter?

Comment: [Border Patrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Border_Patrol_interior_checkpoints), of course.

Comment: Are you DACA then?

Comment: No,I’m not DACA. And I’m not sure I just hear that there will be a checkpoint.

Comment: @Amandacaune what's your immigration status then?  Border patrol seems not to think very much of EADs, but the document they would preferto see depends on your immigration status.

Comment: I’m applying to become a resident.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a pending adjustment of status application?

Comment: Yes,I have a pending status application.

Comment: If you have a receipt (for I-797C?) for the AOS, take a copy with you.

Answer (score 1):

Neither an EAD nor Advance Parole are relevant to your ability to stay in the US. EAD is for employment authorization and Advance Parole is for entering the US. Because you have a pending I-485 (Adjustment of Status) application, you can stay in the US regardless of whether you have status or not. Make sure to bring your I-485 receipt with you in case you run into a CBP checkpoint.